# Cronjobs are not running by www-data

Tags: permissions, php, cron, laravel

I'm working on a **Laravel app** deployed on a Kubernetes cluster, and I need to set a cronjob to run php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run.

I'm using **php:7.4-fpm-alpine** image.

The following script is used to generate the cronjob:

```
#!/bin/sh

crontab -l > mycron

touch /var/cronlogs.txt

echo "* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /var/cronlogs.txt 2>&1" >> mycron

crontab mycron

rm mycron
```

The cronjob is working fine, but suddenly I faced an issue that when some of the php artisan commands executed by the cronjob, it writes the log in 'storage/logs' with root permissions which is deny www-data requests from writing logs.

I tried to change the user who run the cronjob to www-data, but when I did that the cronjob is not running anymore.

**What I Did:**

1- I changed "**crontab -l > mycron**" to "**crontab -u www-data -l > mycron**" and "**crontab mycron**" to "**crontab -u www-data mycron**" in the script.

2- I changed the ownership of **/var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data** to www-data:www-data

3- I ran crond command.

There were no errors when I ran crond command but the job did not start.

The cronjob in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root works fine -with the changing log file issue-.

The cronjob in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data doesn't work.

How to make cronjobs run by www-data? and if this is not the solution how to prevent php artisan commands from writing logs by root user?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; are we to guess?

Comment: [Here is the droid you are looking for](https://askubuntu.com/a/210545/1222991).

Comment: @guiverc
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.16.3
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.16"

Comment: @matigo /etc/crontab not found, should I create it manually?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.